# How to send HTTP Delete request with custom headers?

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, http-delete

I have a web server running on an EC2 node. There is an endpoint which accepts HTTP DELETE requests. It accepts the requests and proceeds with the intended functionality only if some certain headers are found in the DELETE request it send. What would be the easiest way to test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://www.hurl.it/

Set the type the DELETE, and click Add Headers to add the headers you want.